# Query return from mysql into php table not at the top

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new at using PHP and am trying to populate a table with data from a MySQL database, but the results that display are dotted all over the table and are not in their relevant columns at the top of the table.

Attached is a screenshot of where I need the data to be.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
$server = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx"); 
  $db = mysql_select_db("xxxxxx", $server); 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores"); 

?>  


<html>
<head>
<title>Stores Tracker Dashboard</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<p align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Stores Tracker Dashboard</strong></font></p>

<table align="center" border="1" width="90%">
<tr>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Not Started</strong></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>In Transit</strong></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Awaiting Build</strong></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Being Built</strong></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>On Return</strong></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Received Back</strong></font></td>
</tr>


<?php

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>

<tr>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "Not Started") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "In Transit") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "Awaiting Build") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "Being Built") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "On Return from CFC2") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><?php if ($row['status'] == "Received") { echo $row['ticket'], '&nbsp; (', $row['site'], ')'; }?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: I would highly advise that you go about this with `PDO` connection/queries, not `mysql_connect`

Comment: Sorry but what is a PDO connection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Use . instead of , to concatenate strings in PHP.

Comment: Will changing to PDO and using . To concatenate my strings resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one uses PDO.
Please take your time and learn what is going on there!

```
<?php
  $host = "set_hostname_here";
  $daba = "set_database_here";
  $user = "set_loginname_here";
  $pass = "set_password_here";

  $notstarted = array();
  $intransit = array();
  $awaiting = array();
  $built = array();
  $cfc2 = array();
  $received = array();

  try {    
    //open the PDO-connection to a MySQL-host
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$daba", $user, $pass);

    //error mode set to EXCEPTION (ERRMODE_SILENT or ERRMODE_WARNING are also possible)
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    //execute the query
    $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT status, ticket, site FROM stores');

    //set default fetch mode to FETCH_ASSOC (if you want to try FETCH_OBJ)
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  //go through all results and assign them to the related arrays
  while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $data = $row['ticket'] . '&nbsp; (' . $row['site'] . ')';
    if ($row['status'] == "Not Started") { $notstarted[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "In Transit") { $intransit[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Awaiting Build") { $awaiting[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Being Built") { $built[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "On Return from CFC2") { $cfc2[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Received") { $received[] = $data; }
  }

  //close the connection
  $DBH = null;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stores Tracker Dashboard</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Stores Tracker Dashboard</strong></font></p>

    <table align="center" border="1" width="90%">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Not Started</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>In Transit</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Awaiting Build</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Being Built</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>On Return</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Arial"><strong>Received Back</strong></font></td>
      </tr>

      <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($notstarted),count($intransit),count($awaiting),count($built),count($cfc2),count($received)); $i++) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($notstarted) > $i) echo $notstarted[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($intransit) > $i) echo $intransit[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($awaiting) > $i) echo $awaiting[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($built) > $i) echo $built[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($cfc2) > $i) echo $cfc2[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($received) > $i) echo $received[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      ?>
    </table
  </body>
</html>
```

I used the example of the answer by manassehkatz.
Most of the code relating the PDO connection is nearly copy/pasted from the link given by tadman ...

Good luck for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Each row from the mysql query (yes, should be replaced with PDO, etc. but that is not directly related to the problem) reports the status of one `stores` record. The table is designed to report the values of several on each line - one of each status type. There are a few ways to do this. One way is to populate a set of arrays for the different status codes and then print out the arrays, once completed, as an HTML table. Something like this:

```
$notstarted = array();
$intransit = array();
$awaiting = array();
$built = array();
$cfc2 = array();
$received = array();

// Get all the data into the arrays
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $data = $row['ticket'] . '&nbsp; (' . $row['site'] . ')';
   if ($row['status'] == "Not Started") { $notstarted[] = $data; };
   if ($row['status'] == "In Transit") { $intransit[] = $data; };
   if ($row['status'] == "Awaiting Build") { $awaiting[] = $data; };
   if ($row['status'] == "Being Built") { $built[] = $data; };
   if ($row['status'] == "On Return from CFC2") { $cfc2[] = $data; };
   if ($row['status'] == "Received") { echo $received[] = $data; };
   };

// Loop through all the arrays at once. # of rows will be max of size of all arrays
for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($notstarted),count($intransit),count($awaiting),count($built),count($cfc2),count($received)); $i++) {
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($notstarted) > $i) { print $notstarted[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($intransit) > $i) { print $intransit[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($awaiting) > $i) { print $awaiting[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($built) > $i) { print $built[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($cfc2) > $i) { print $cfc2[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "<td align="center"><font face="Arial">";
   if (count($received) > $i) { print $received[$i]; };
   print "</font></td>";
   print "</tr>";
   };
```

Comment: Hi manassehkatz,  I still am not able to get this working.  The page is blank and looking at the code it all seems in place.  Any other thoughts why nothing is displaying?